# validation of phone number format

Tags: jquery, html, regex

when I want it to check that it have 9 numbers and accept it if less than 9 it will prompt invalid number and I want my 1st digit to start with 8 or 9

```
    var phone           = $("#myForm input[name='Number']").val();
    var phone_regex     = /^[0-9]{9}$/; // reg ex phone check
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to assign an event handler such as `input` or `blur` to the input(s). Then you can use RegExp `test()` to test a pattern. To have it be 9 numbers in length and have to start with an 8 or 9, you could use pattern `/^[8-9]{1}[0-9]{8}$/g`. You would execute `test()` on the pattern then conditionally check the result.

Below is an example demonstrating `input` and `blur` events testing against a regex pattern:

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="number1">Phone (Change)</label>
    <input type="text" name="number1">
    <br>
    <span id="error1" class="error"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="number2">Phone (Change)</label>
    <input type="text" name="number2">
    <br>
    <span id="error2" class="error"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $form = $('#myForm');

  var $input1 = $form.find('input[name="number1"]');
  var $input2 = $form.find('input[name="number2"]');

  var $error1 = $form.find('#error1');
  var $error2 = $form.find('#error2');

  var pattern = /^[8-9]{1}[0-9]{8}$/g;

  $input1.on('input', function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      var result = pattern.test(value);

      if(result) {
          console.log('Valid input');
      }
      else {
          $error1.text('Please enter a valid number');
      }
   });

  $input2.on('blur', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    var result = pattern.test(value);

    if(result) {
        console.log('Valid input');
    }
    else {
        $error2.text('Please enter a valid number');
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90p0royx/) demonstrating the functionality.

Comment: I have changed /^[0-9]{9}$/; to /^[8-9]{1}[0-9]{8}$/g; but it's still not working tho

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to use the `input` event to detect change on every change within the input box. I've included a jsfiddle demonstrating the functionality.